# Read table from web intro R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am trying to read this table from a website
https://www.the-burgenland-bunch.org/ChurchRecords/Kukmirn/KukmirnMarriages.htm

ScreenShot of the table

[image]

I need to read it in order to find rows that match certain names ( i was thinking about using grep() actually), therefore i would like to get a dataframe pretty similar to the one that is originally in the website, does anyone know how to do it in R?

PS: note that the website ending is ".htm"
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with `rvest` package :

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.the-burgenland-bunch.org/ChurchRecords/Kukmirn/KukmirnMarriages.htm'
data <- url %>% read_html() %>% html_table(header = TRUE) %>% .[[1]]

head(data)
#        Date            Groom Age Widower    Hometown              Bride Age Widow of
#1 1828.01.29   Schedl Michael   - widower Kaltenbrunn   Deutsch Theresia   -         
#2 1828.02.05    Tauss Andreas   -         Kaltenbrunn    Wagner Theresia   -         
#3 1828.02.05   Kogelmann Adam   -         Kaltenbrunn Schmaldienst Maria   -         
#4 1828.02.05 Erkinger Mathias   -         Kaltenbrunn     Weber Theresia   -         
#5 1828.02.05  Brunner Mathias   -             Zahling   Pummer Elisabeth   -         
#6 1828.02.12    Boantl Johann   -             Zahling  Tamerler Theresia   -     
    
#     Hometown    Groom's father Groom's mother    Bride's father Bride's mother
#1 Kaltenbrunn                 -              -    Deutsch Johann        Susanna
#2 Kaltenbrunn        Tauss Adam          Maria     Wagner Johann      Elisabeth
#3 Kaltenbrunn Kogelmann Mathias       Theresia Schmaldienst Adam       Theresia
#4 Kaltenbrunn  Erkinger Mathias          Maria     Weber Michael          Maria
#5     Zahling     Brunner Georg          Maria    Pummer Mathias      Katharina
#6     Zahling     Boantl Johann      Katharina  Tamerler Mathias      Katharina
```